# Combine provided queryDSL predicates with predefined queries

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest

In context of Spring Data REST I would like to expose search/filter functionality on the result of the single query.
If my query was findAll that would be out of the box  (it would be enough to extend `QueryDslPredicateExecutor`). But how can I combine my custom query (findMyNotes) with additional filtering provided by the user (that are marked as done). I mean something like:

```
@Entity
class Note {
    @Id
    private UUID id;
    private UUID personId;
    private String status;
    private String text;
}

@RepositoryRestResource(path = "notes", itemResourceRel = "notes", collectionResourceRel = "notes")
interface NoteRepository extends JpaRepository<Note, UUID>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Note> {

    @RestResource(path="notes/my")
    @Query("select n from Note n where n.personId=:creatorId")
    Page<Note> findDone(@Param("creatorId") UUID creatorId, Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable);
}
```

I didn't find anything out of the box. Therefore I was thinking to use AOP and:

1. have multiple paths (multiple `@RestResource` ?) that map to `org.springframework.data.querydsl.QueryDslPredicateExecutor#findAll(Predicate, org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)`
2. have my own annotation that would point me to the method that returns the original queryDSL Predicate (contents of `@Query` in my example)
3. by AOP calculate AND of those two predicates and pass it as a parameter to findAll method

The problem is that I don't know how to do the first point (apart from hacking it in servlet filters) - map multiple paths to the same findAll method.

Or alternatively is there maybe something working out of the box that I missed?

Comment: Did you find a solution Marcin?